# What is the best way to test SSL-only URLs with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capybara

I've gone round and round trying to come up with the cleanest / easiest way to write request specs for certain pages of my site. **I basically need a way to get Capybara to load pages that only accessible over https**. Here are the pertinent details:

- I'm currently using RSpec, Capybara and FactoryGirl on Rails 3.1.0
- Its an e-commerce site. Some controllers force all actions ssl using the new `force_ssl` method in the controller class definition while some do not. I need the cart and checkout pages to be always https://, of course, while the rest of the site should remain accessible over http://.
- I would be OK with somehow stubbing the SSL aspect of the requests if only I knew how to do it!

I'm sure many people out there have faced this same challenge. How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

What Capybara driver are you using? It should work fine with Selenium.